# Chromium Content Module (Content Shell) Webview on GTK window

Tags: webview, gtk, chromium

I am planning on using the content module instead of the Embed Framework of chromium because of the size.
My Current problem is that I can't find the api documentation, So i don't know how to make a standalone  webview inside a window using it, or embed it on a GTK window. Also, my program is open source so It has to work across multiple Operational Systems

Comment: You won't find documentation of Chromium for everything. Looks like the documentation for content API is lacking too. This is all I could find: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/content/public/README.md So you might have to go through the source code to find out how it works

Comment: thanks, It helps a lot

Comment: @lmtr0 Please share what you have used to build it.

Comment: I've moved on to use tauri